# Database problem

Tags: wp-admin

I have problem with database. Front page is working properly but when I want to access backoffice mysite.com/wp-admin I am redirecting to /wp-admin/install.php therefore I opened phpmyadmin and I saw that there is empty database..no columns, rows, nothing but front site and all pages working good is that normal? XD . What is going on? I have w3 total cache and cloud flare. Maybye my site is working only because my database is cached? How can I revive my database? Please help me, I have no backups.

Comment: talk with your hosting

Comment: try it after uninstalling w3 total cache

Answer (score 0):

Your database is not cached but the HTML files are cached by w3 total cache and cloud flare. If have not backed up you database there is not much you can do to easily restore your site. They only thing you can do at this stage is grab a copy of your site from cached version, I use a mac app called SiteSucker you point it to website and it will down load it as HTML. If did that you then re-upload it as a static site while you slowly reconstruct your Wordpress site.

For future reference I use UpdraftPlus and back my site (database and files) to Amazon S3 it's super cheep I do about 10 websites for around a $1 a month.